# Method to return boolean when LeftMouseIsDown

Tags: java, mouse

How do I make method that will return a boolean value
if a user is holding their left mouse button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a MouseListener and to process the `MOUSE_PRESSED` event. You can read about it in detail [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html)